# Unable to receive SMS receive broadcast on Galaxy SIII running 4.1.1

Tags: android, sms, galaxy, samsung-mobile, android-broadcast

I have this problem **only on Samsung Galaxy SIII** running Android 4.1.1. There is no problem on Samsung Galaxy Ace and Samsung Galaxy Y. The broadcast SMS received is not firing up, when SMS is received. No other SMS app is installed on the phone.

I am using the following code to receive the SMS broadcast

```
    smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onReceive of smsReceiver");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        // Create messages for each incoming PDU
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }
        for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
            //do something
        }
    }
};

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

    intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY - 1);

} else {
    // set Interger.MAX_VALUE because other apps like Handcent are intercepting
    intentFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

}
intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
// register receiver for receive SMS
registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I have set the following permission in the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

I don't have logcat access. 
I have spend last two days trying to find the cause in the maze of Android but no help.

Comment: Have you tried other existing third-party SMS apps to see if they work on this device?

Comment: No, I should have done that first. Let me try now.

Comment: It is not clear under what method you have registered the receiver. Just to be on the safer side (and as you mentioned that there's no other messaging app on the device). Can you register the receiver in the app manifest.

Comment: Any reason why you suggest so?